# Start FragmentTransaction from within ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` with several rows.  Each row has a `button`.

I want the button to start a FragmentTransaction to replace the Fragment that the ListView is in.

However, in the `getView()` method of the `Adapter`, this line does not work:

`FragmentTransaction t = getContext().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

It does not like the context.

*Can this be done in this way or does the Transaction have to happen elsewhere?*

Comment: What error are you getting, specifically?

Comment: The error is : `The Method getSupportFragmentManager is undefined for the type Context`

Comment: Did you end up finding a suitable answer, if so what was the solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is only defined for the class `FragmentActivity`, not for `Context`. Thus, the compiler can't resolve the call if you try to call it on an object of type `Context`.

You can use reflection to do this in a safe way. This will always work as long as you pass your FragmentActivity as the `Context`. Note: FragmentActivity is a subclass of Context, and thus you can pass FragmentActivity wherever you can pass Context.

So use this code instead:

```
if (getContext() instanceof FragmentActivity) {
    // We can get the fragment manager
    FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity(getContext()));
    FragmentTransaction t = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
}
```

Comment: What if it is not an instance of fragmentActivity, and it is just an activity... how do you go about this

Comment: @Lion789 Well a non-fragment Activity wouldn't have a FragmentManager, and thus no `getSupportFragmentManager`or `getFragmentManager`, so you can't use Fragments with it.

Comment: how can i use `getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, Fragment_home.newInstance(),
                            Fragment_home.TAG).commit();` in side array adapter.it getting error when i use it according to your solution

Answer (score 34):

First get the context in your Constructor and then try following code,

```
FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: can we cast Activity (parent extends Activity but not FragmentActivity)?

Comment: No, Because Activity doesn't have Fragment Manager. So to use getSupportFragmentManager() method you need to cast instance of FragmentActivity only.

Comment: Thank you I was passing the FragmentManager as parameter and using that from adapter but it was showing parameter mismatch this one worked :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you to pass `FragmentManager` instance to the `Adapter` constructor like that:

```
public class YourAdapter extends...

    private FragmentManage mFragmentManager;        

    public YourAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }
```

And use it explicitly:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

That should give you posibility to initialize `Adapter` with either `Fragment.getFragmentManager()` or `FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` instance, since they are pointed at the same object

Comment: Doing  `public YourAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {` cause an error that says `Implicit Super constructor ArrayAdapter<Review>() is undefined.  Must implicitly invoke another constructor`?

Comment: So, you are overriding `ArrayAdapter`? You should call `super()` constructor with corresponding params. If you provide the source code of your adapter's constructor I can provide exact line