# create new fragment within array Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have ListView (inside Fragment) that gets populated with arrayAdapter.I have apply button in each view of listView. I made a listener for apply button i would like to start new fragment once i click on button. And i got nullPointerException at getFragmentManager(). i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090226/starting-a-fragment-inside-arrayadapter), [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329451/start-fragmenttransaction-from-within-arrayadapter) but could not able to solve my problem.

This is my ArrayAdaptor code:

```
public class FullTimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Datalist> {
    private Context mContext;
    private FullTimeJobs mFragment;
    private List<Datalist> datalists = new ArrayList<>();

    public FullTimeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Datalist> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
        mContext = context;
        datalists = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        View listView = convertView;
        if (listView == null) {
            listView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.full_time_datalist, parent, false);
        }

        Button btnApply = listView.findViewById(R.id.part_btn_apply);
        btnApply.setText("Apply");

        btnApply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment;
                fragment = new Apply();
                FragmentManager fm = fragment.getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
        return listView;

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-16 17:00:59.566 10150-10150/com.example.innobles.internapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.innobles.internapp, PID: 10150
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.innobles.internapp.Adapter.FullTimeAdapter$2.onClick(FullTimeAdapter.java:90)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4448)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18461)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5065)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what error you getting, share logcat!

Comment: use `((Activity)context). getFragmentManager();`

Comment: `create new fragment within array Adapter`? Question's title is vague.

Comment: @HemantParmar updated logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @JyotiJK did not work ! i have tried that

Comment: Which line is line 90?

Comment: use  getActivity().getFragmentManager(); instead

Comment: @DavidWasser ` FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment);`

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig getting error saying `can not resolve methods getActivity()`

Comment: In general your architecture is wrong. An `Adapter` should not be responsible for creating a `Fragment`. This responsibility should be in your `Activity`. The adapter should simply call a method on the `Activity` that indicates what button was clicked. The `Activity` should then decide what to do about it. The `Activity` has access to the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: @DavidWasser correct . Hey you can use delegates to get callback in activity from your adapter and open fragment there not in adapter

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you for valuable suggestion  i will definitely take care from now

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig can you give me lil example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works but do not know how..

here what i did :

```
 ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Apply()).commit();
```

instead of

```
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an interface as

```
interface CustomOnClick {
   void onCustomOnClick();
}
```

implement this interface in your Fragment from where you are applying adapter and also pass your activity instance in your adapter constructor In your adapter create interface object like

```
CustomOnClick listener;
```

and in adapter constructor initialize it

```
public FullTimeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Datalist> list, CustomOnClick listener) {
        super(context, 0, list);
        this.listener=listener;
        mContext = context;
        datalists = list;
    }
```

in adapter's on click method just write following line and move remaining code in Fragments's onCustomClick() method

```
listener.onCustomClick();
```

and in your framents' onCustomClick method use getActivity().getFragmentManger()

Comment: getting NPE at `getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Apply()).commit();`

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.innobles.internapp, PID: 27832
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.innobles.internapp.fragment.FullTimeJobs.onCustomClick(FullTimeJobs.java:62)
        at com.example.innobles.internapp.Adapter.FullTimeAdapter$2.onClick(FullTimeAdapter.java:90)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4448)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18461)`

Comment: are you successfully able to get callback in onCustomClick() method??

Comment: just remove everything from that method and simply log something

Comment: yes .. when i,m putting log then while clicking button log is triggered.I think problem is with creating new fragment somewhere is context

Comment: Okay Use this to open fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

Answer (score 0):

Try `FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();`

Comment: @JosefAdamcik Take a minute and read [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) before declaring this isn't an answer